# In unity, How do I transfer data from a C# script to a shader?

Tags: unity, c#

Let's say I have a C# script that has a variable inside it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class flow : MonoBehaviour{
    float r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,1);
}
```

I want to access this variable from inside an unlit shader. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you're looking for is this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloat.html

example:

```
Material.SetFloat("_VariableName",variableValue);
```

where Material is the material with the shader you want to send the value to.

You can find more similar functions for different value types (color, vector, etc) in the public methods part of this documentation page:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.html

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate on how I should use this function? Adding that line of code into a script and creating a variable named rando in the sdf shader is giving me an error. https://imgur.com/a/b4wjfwo

Comment: Where did you declare the variable named `sdf`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DMGregory, I figured out what the solution to my question was.

In the properties section of the shader, I created a float.

```
properties{
radius ("radius", float) = 1
}
```

Then, I created a private material in the C# script, named the material, and then use the SetFloat function to set the value of the float.

```
private Material sdf;

void Start(){
    float r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,1);
    sdf = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    sdf.SetFloat("radius", r);
}

void Update(){
    //Fun fact: if you initialize r and SetFloat in Update(), then the value of radius is different for each frame.
}
```

Then, initialize radius in the shader and its value should be updated by the script.